# Find out HDD usage of binary data in a field

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

In a collection with a field `image` that contains images (BinData).  I want to find out how many % of the DB are used by the images. What is the most efficient way to calculate the total size of all images?

I want to avoid fetching all images from the DB server, so I came up with this code:

```
mapper = Code("""
           function() {
             var n = 0;
             if (this.image) {
               n = this.image.length();
             }
             emit('sizes', n);
           }
           """)
reducer = Code("""
               function(key, sizes) {
                 var total = 0;
                 for (var i = 0; i < sizes.length; i++) {
                   total += sizes[i];
                 }
               }
               return total;
               """)
result = db.files.map_reduce(mapper, reducer, "image_sizes")
```

During the execution memory usage of mongodb gets quite high, it looks as if the whole data is loaded into memory.  How can this be optimized?  Also, does it make sense to call `this.image.length()` in order to find out how many Bytes the images occupy on the harddrive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not avoid loading all the data into memory. MongoDB treats a document as its atomic unit, and by querying all documents, it will pull in all documents into memory.

As an alternative, what might possibly help you is just to see how many bytes a collection takes up, but that of course only works if the only thing you have stored in your collection are images. On the shell, you can do this with:

```
db.files.stats()
```

Which has the field `storageSize` that shows you how much storage is needed for your images approximately. This is not nearly as accurate as going through all your images though.

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer my quesstion.  I've seen that `.length()` yields a different result than downloading each image and then looking at the file sizes.

Comment: The main answer was still that you need to loop through everything. I've updated it now so that it shows "storageSize" as merely a faster , but less accurate alternative.